# .getLabel function is not working on blackberry 9800

Tags: java, blackberry

I'm having problems with a button that fires a timer. If I take away all the if statements it works fine so there is nothing wrong with the timer code. This same code works fine in every other phone I have tried 8900, storm, etc..

It's only on the 9800 that it fails and runs to the end of the if statements.

Is there a change in the getLabel?

My code is:

```
startbtn.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {
    public void fieldChanged(Field field1, int context) {
        /////sound file
        try {
            Manager.playTone(ToneControl.C4, 100, 50);
        } catch (MediaException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (startbtn.getLabel() == "START"){
            startbtn.setLabel("STOP!");
            startTimer();
        } else if (startbtn.getLabel() == "STOP!"){
            startbtn.setLabel("RESET");
            stopTimer();
        } else if (startbtn.getLabel() == "RESET"){
            dismiss();
            //// RESET SCREEN AFTER
        }
    }
});
```

I hope someone can help I can't find an answer anywhere.

Comment: Debug your project and check what is returned by `getLabel()`.

Answer (score 2):

I would worry you that correct comparison of strings in Java is `str1.equals(str2)` and also there is usually precondition `str1 != null`.

But there is exception in cases similar to yours. Just introduce constants:

```
private static final String START_LABEL = "START!";
private static final String STOP_LABEL = "STOP!";
private static final String RESET_LABEL = "RESET";
```

And use constants in if statements. Like this:

```
if (START_LABEL == startbtn.getLabel()) {}
```

More about `String` comparison in Java [here](http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-string-comparison) and [here](http://www.zparacha.com/java-string-comparison/#.UCIl703iagk).

I hope your app requires only English localization. It is more readable to use Camel case notation for variable naming.

Comment: Thanks... All sorted with .equals